# Rails edit form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form for a user, which should be fairly simple but something happens that I can't figure out why, let me start with routes :

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users, :only => [:show, :index, :edit, :update] do
      collection do
        get :archived
      end
    end
end
```

Edit form :

```
= simple_form_for(@user, validate: true) do |f| 
  = render 'fields', f: f, object: @user
  .actions
    = f.submit t('general.save_changes'), class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
    or
    = link_to t('general.cancel'), redirect_back
```

Fields with just one field to start of with:

```
= render 'shared/error_messages', object: object

.form-group
  .row
    = f.input :created_at
```

User controller :

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ap "ppp #{@user.inspect}"
end

def update
  ap "hereee"
end
```

When I click the link for editing particular user i.e

```
http://localhost:5000/admin/users/1/edit
```

I get this error message :

```
NoMethodError at /admin/users/1/edit
undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000098a7100>:0x00000008eb1cb8>
```

I have no idea what I've done wrong here. I've tried restarting the rails server but same thing occurs. What else can I do, I've been looking into this for some time now?

Here are rake routes :

```
archived_admin_users GET    /admin/users/archived(.:format)                              admin/users#archived
admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                                      admin/users#index
edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)                             admin/users#edit
admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                  admin/users#show 
           PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                  admin/users#update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, @user], validate: true) do |f|
```

Comment: thanks, thank worked. Can you explain your answer please? I'll accept anyway

Comment: That's usual Rails `form_for` (which is used by simple_form) usage for namespaced routes. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html , section 2.3.1 Dealing with Namespaces